# PyQt5 Updating a painting on an image

Tags: qpainter

Using PyQt5 QPainter to draw a region of interest box on an image that I want to be able to dynamically update over time. In the sample code I draw a rect onto an image and , wait 1 second, draw a second rectangle onto the image and then a second later, a third rectangle. I want previous rectangles to disappear. Problem I'm having is that the rectangles are all persistent. The repaint() call does not wipe the graphics slate clean as I would like. Any ideas?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
     def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()

          self.setGeometry(150,150,500,500)
          self.ImageWindow = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
          self.ImageWindow.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0,0,150,150))

          self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)

          self.state = 0

          self.timer.start(1)

          self.pixmap = QPixmap('marvel.png')
          self.pixmap.scaled(QtCore.Qsize(100,100))

          self.timer.timeout.connect(self.prepareDrawing)

     def prepareDrawing(self):
          self.state += 1
          self.timer.start(1000)
          self.ImageWindow.repaint()
          if self.state == 1:
               pen = QPen(Qt.red,2, Qt.SolidLine)
               self.drawRect(0,0,100,100,pen)
          elif self.state == 2:
               pen = QPen(Qt.blue,2, Qt.DashLine)
               self.drawRect(20,0,100,100,pen)
          elif self.state == 2:
               pen = QPen(Qt.green,2, Qt.DashDotLine)
               self.drawRect(40,0,50,50,pen)

     def drawRect(self,x,y,w,h,p):
          painter = QPainter(self)
          painter.begin(self.pixmap)
          painter.setPen(p)
          painter.drawRect(x,y,w,h)
          painter.end()
          self.ImageWindow.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
          self.show()

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```